# Simple Ajax Update Form with $_POST and $_GET

Tags: php, ajax, form-submit

So I'm trying to understand jQuery's .ajax function so that when I create my sites CMS I can update content on the backend asynchronously. I'm creating a simple form to start out. I pass the id of the database using php in the action href of the form. I pull the data from the form and convert it to json using the .serialize() jQuery function and then pass the action and the data into the .ajax function. On my the backend I use php to pull the $_POST and $_GET items and update the database accordingly. Everything works except that the site actually links to my backend php site... I just figure this out actually but I can post the answer for future references for people. Let me know if my answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I was using type="submit" for the update input for the form. Because I was using action = "mybackendhref" in the form This caused it to link to the actually page that I wanted to use .ajax to push the data to instead. Changing to input type="button" caused everything to work smoothly.

*By "mybackendhref" I mean the actual site I want to push the data to using .ajax.